# onnx model in C#

Tags: c#, onnx, ml.net

I am trying to run a machine learning model which I built in Python in C# using ml.net. I converted the model to .onnx (ONNX v7) and am following this tutorial almost exactly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automl-onnx-model-dotnet

I am getting an CLR/System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when I try to run a prediction:

```
var testInput = new OnnxInput { Input4 = new[] { 19f, 1245f, 106f, 87f } };
var prediction = onnxPredictionEngine.Predict(testInput);
```

When I inspect the onnxPredictionEngine OutputSchema I see below:

```
[0] [Column] : {input_1: Vector<single>}
[1] [Column] : {input_1: Vector<single>, 1, 30}
```

The inputs in my model (which I can see using Netron) are below:

```
name: input_1
type: float32[unk__6,4]
```

The outputs in my model are below:

```
name: dense_9
type: float32[unk__7,30]
```

I expect the input array size of 4 (as shown in the onnx model), but the OutputSchema[0] has size of 0. Is this where the issue is? If so, is there some way to tell the OutputSchema[0] to expect array of size 4?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add in the VectorType into the class definition.

Below:

```
class OnnxInput
{
    [VectorType(4)]
    [ColumnName("input_1")]
    public float[]? Input4 { get; set; }
}

class OnnxOutput
{
    [VectorType(30)]
    [ColumnName("dense_9")]
    public float[]? Output30 { get; set; }
}
```